# CSS background gif image is not looping with repeat

Tags: html, css

CSS background gif image is not looping with the repeat. I have following code, but it's not working. Both images are rendered top of another, but the gif file is not looping.

```css
.decoration {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 365px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=34&txt=365%C3%97650&w=365&h=650") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-position: center center;
}
image-holder {
  width: 269px;
  height: 477px;
  margin: 77px 48px;
  background: url("http://bbsimg.ngfiles.com/1/24309000/ngbbs509571c17019a.gif") repeat center;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="decoration">
  <div class="image-holder">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to target image-holder you need to put "." in front of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.decoration {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 365px;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: -10px;
   background: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=34&txt=365%C3%97650&w=365&h=650") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-position: center center;
}

.image-holder {
    width: 269px;
    height: 477px;
    margin: 77px 48px;
    background: url("http://bbsimg.ngfiles.com/1/24309000/ngbbs509571c17019a.gif") repeat center;
    background-position: center center;
    
}
  
    
}
```

```html
<div class="decoration">
    <div class="image-holder">              
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using a dummy gif here. Try replacing the gif url with yours.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I found, the problem was my gif file not css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the background-size: cover; at your image-holder ans also the background-position tag